# wordpress post view counter increase by calling rest api

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, wordpress-rest-api

i have some custom post meta for counting view,

[image of api (http://www.test.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nsnxv.jpg)

i need update (increase ++) post view counter when i get "http://www.test.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1234" (1234 is post id)

i search a lot but i don't find any thing, although i fine this code :

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'base', '/views/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'post_view_counter_function',
  ));
});
function post_view_counter_function( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
  $post_id = $request['id'];
if ( FALSE === get_post_status( $post_id ) ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'error_no_post', 'Not a post id', array( 'status' => 404 ) );
  } else {
    $current_views = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'views', true );
    $views = $current_views + 1;
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'views', $views );
    return $views;
  }
}
```

BUT the problem of above code is being separate and custom endpoint, i need increase view counter (cd_plays in image) by every html get request the post api (http://www.test.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1234)

please give me a guide, i stuck about this

Answer (score 0):

In this code many changes
1.   register_rest_route( 'base', '/views/(?P\d+)', array(

Change  to  register_rest_route( 'base/v1',
 if you want no  major changes so this url ,
http://www.test.com/wp-json/base/v1/views/1234

Answer (score 0):

You can also limit the posts per page you're fetching to 1 so you're not getting all your WordPress posts just to get the posts to count.

http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=1

Thanks